# JavaScript | Trying to add a animated character from sketchfab but is not animating on website

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, frontend

I have downloaded the .gltf file of an animated character from sketch fab but after adding it to my website the character is not animating there, I am new to the three.js.

```
let scene,camera,renderer;

function init(){
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    //scene.background = new THREE.
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,1,5000);
    camera.rotation.y = 45/180*Math.PI;
    camera.position.x = 800;
    camera.position.y = 100;
    camera.position.z = 500;
    
    
    
    hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040,100);
    scene.add(hlight);

    directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff,100);
    directionalLight.position.set(0,1,0);
    directionalLight.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    ligt = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
    ligt.position.set(0,300,500);
    scene.add(ligt);

    ligt1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
    ligt.position.set(500,100,0);
    scene.add(ligt1);

    ligt2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
    ligt.position.set(0,100,-500);
    scene.add(ligt2);

    ligt3 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
    ligt.position.set(-500,300,0);
    scene.add(ligt3);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera,renderer.domElement);
    controls.addEventListener('change',renderer);

    
    let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('./3drobo/scene.gltf',function(gltf){
        car = gltf.scene.children[0];
        car.scale.set(0.5,0.5,0.5);
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
        animate();
    });
    
}
function animate (){
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
init();
```

this is the code I am currently using. I really don't know how to load an animated character to the scene

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `THREE.AnimationMixer` to animate gltf-animations in your loader callback:

```
let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('./3drobo/scene.gltf',function(gltf){
        car = gltf.scene.children[0];
        car.scale.set(0.5,0.5,0.5);
        
        let mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( gltf.scene );
        let action = mixer.clipAction( gltf.animations[ 0 ] );
        action.play();

        scene.add(gltf.scene);
    });
```

Source and further information: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/easiest-way-to-play-skeletal-animation-from-gltf/7792